# Непонятная ошибка при обращении к классу

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

При работе с наследованием классов выскакивает непонятная ошибка. Есть подозрение, что это из-за отсутствия get и set(однако есть конструктор) методов.
Ниже приведу 2 листинга: 1 - это основная программа, а 2 это листинг класса `TRectangle`. Класс `TTriangle` пустой. Также прилагаю класс-родитель (там просто пустышка с виртуальными методами-пустышками.

```
//основной файл программы
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TRectangle.h"
#include "TTriangle.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
TRectangle *Rect1 = new TRectangle;
Rect1.Move();
return 0;
}
```

Класс для прямоугольника с переопределённым методом `Move`. В классе `TFigure` (виртуальный класс-родитель) является пустым, содержит виртуальный метод `Move`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TRectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

TRectangle::TRectangle()
{
rx1 = 0;  //    x1,y1              x2,y2
ry1 = 0;  //    x3,y3              x4,y4
rx2 = 10;
ry2 = 0;
rx3 = 0;
ry3 = 4;
rx4 = 10;
ry4 = 4;
rStepX = 0;
rStepY = 0;
}


TRectangle::~TRectangle()
{
}


void TRectangle::Move()
{
cin >> rStepX;
cin >> rStepY;
cout << "rectangle is moved!" << endl;
rx1 = rx1 + rStepX; //здесь происходит переопределение метода Move
rx2 = rx2 + rStepX; //и в нём происходит прибавление к точкам данного             расстояния движения rStep
rx3 = rx3 + rStepX;
rx4 = rx4 + rStepX;
ry1 = ry1 + rStepY;
ry2 = ry2 + rStepY;
ry3 = ry3 + rStepY;
ry4 = ry4 + rStepY;
cout << rx1 << " " << rx2 << " " << rx3 << " " << rx4 << endl;
cout << ry1 << " " << ry2 << " " << ry3 << " " << ry4 << endl;
}
```

Вопрос: почему возникает ошибка:

> Ошибка 1   error C2228: выражение слева от ".Move" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение    *[полный путь стёрт мною]* classes_legacy_v2.cpp    10  1   Classes_Legacy_V2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rect1` у вас указатель!

```
Rect1->Move()
```

Вы используете не то выражение; для обращения через указатель надо использовать `->` (или `(*Rect1).Move()`).

P.S. Вы не из Java в C++ пришли? :)

Comment: Хорошо, а можете разъяснить суть этой стрелки. Сколько в плюсах уже прошли, я так до сих пор и не понял её суть. На вики читал, что это обращение к объекту на который ссылается динамическая структура(вроде так, если своими словами., а дословно: a->b Объект B от Объекта на который ссылается А

Comment: Я студент-первокурсник. Грызу гранит науки) доселе очень слабо писал на PascalABC .NET

Comment: Если у вас есть объект с членами (данными, функциями) `obj`, как вы обращаетесь к ним? Ну, как и хотели - c точкой: `obj.func()`. Но если у вас указатель, его надо сначала *разыменовать*, превратив в объект: `*obj`. И тогда обращаться через точку: `(*obj).func()` - именно так, со скобками, из-за приоритетов операций. Тоскливо? Еще бы. Вот и введен оператор `->` как замена для этой записи: `(*obj).func()` тождественно `obj->func()`. Вот и все. Насколько помню, в Паскале это `obj^.func`...

Comment: @Harry: Оператор `->` изначально появился в доисторическом С и при этом его функциональность была более широкой, чем функциональность комбинации из `*` и `.`. Поэтому говорить, что `->` был введен чисто как "замена" для сокращения записи было бы неверно. Изначально оператор `->` имел и свои собственные причины для существования. Лишь позже (в K&R C) он стал полным эквивалентом комбинации из `*` и `.`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас опечатка - неправильный синтаксис. Для указателя должно быть выражение обращения к члену класса как

```
Rect1->Move();
```

или как

```
( *Rect1 ).Move();
```